# Razor view is not refreshed after controller method call

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have a Razor view in my web app which contains data I get from an API. There is a dropdown list in this view, and selecting an entry in this dropdown list triggers an ajax call to my web app controller, and the view should be updated by this call, but for some reason it isn't.

When return View("Index", model); is reached, data inside model object has changed, but the view is not updated with this data. When I refresh the page using the button in my browser, the view is updated as expected.

The method called by the ajax call is this one, it is inherited from a base controller and this part works fine :

```
[HttpGet("abonnements/{idAbonnement}")]
public override async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAbonnementCourant(long idAbonnement)
{
    UpdateAbonnementCookie(idAbonnement);
    return await Index(idAbonnement);
}
```

And the index method called by UpdateAbonnementCourant in the same controller gets the updated data from the API but doesn't refresh the view :

```
[HttpGet("{idAbonnement?}")]
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, Duration = 0)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(long? idAbonnement)
{
    if (!idAbonnement.HasValue && long.TryParse(HttpContext.Request.Cookies["idAbonnementSelectionne"], out long idAbonnementCookie))
        idAbonnement = idAbonnementCookie;

    string uri = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

    if (idAbonnement.HasValue)
        uri = $"{uri}/{idAbonnement}";

    HttpResponseMessage response = await _apiHttpClient.GetAsync(uri);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
        {
            var model = new HtmlModel
            {
                ContenuHtml = new HtmlString(json)
            };
            return View("Index", model);
        }
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

It looks like a caching issue but ResponseCache(NoStore = true) did not solve the problem. I don't know what I am missing, I need some help.

Comment: your ajax request fetches the whole view result from `View("Index", model)`? Well that's a mistake. It really depends on how you update your view after the ajax request success. Usually you need to return `json` and update the view using javascript or at least return a partial view and update to the HTML of some element.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see what's wrong. I didn't realize that return View("Index", model) was the actual response to the ajax call. I fixed my problem by a simple javascript page refresh when the ajax call is successful. Nonetheless I should definitely change that to the approach you suggested, updating only the json displayed directly through the ajax call.